# C# default constructor for "System" namespace class objects

Tags: c#, object, constructor, namespaces

I am wondering what the default constructor would be for predefined classes/classes contained in the `.NET Framework` *Class Library* (such as the "Console" class). Thanks!

Would [Object Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2) be the answer?

```
using System;

class AccountTest
{
   static void Main()
   {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello World!");
        Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the source code of those classes? This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - **why** are you asking this?

Answer (score 0):

"[If you don't provide a constructor for your class, C# creates one by default that instantiates the object and sets member variables to the default values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors#default-constructors)". This holds true for *most* classes, even those within the .NET Base Class Library.

In the case of the [`Console`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?view=netframework-4.7.2) class however, it is marked as `static` and since "[a static class cannot be instantiated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)" it provides no constructor.

Comment: Note that setting/initializing member fields to their default values is not related to constructors at all. Initializing the member fields of an object happens at instantiation of the object (initialization of its storage space) _before_ any constructor (no matter if default or constructor declared by type) is being called. It is no coincidence that the default value of any type is being represented at their storage location as zero bytes, as thus object initialization basically comes down to zeroing out the storage location for the object (or value) no matter their actual type...